# Removing a fixed word from a list of strings?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings like this:

```
string_list=["abcdefg","qwrbcdqqq","ophdkjhfkbcd","jdfkvndn"]
```

Notice that a word exists in some of them (here `bcd`) but the location of this word is not fixed and changes in each string. Now how do I remove this word from those strings if I know what the word is?

Edit: Target list is:

```
target_list=["aefg","qwrqqq","ophdkjhfk","jdfkvndn"]
```

Comment: Please clarify your desired output; two of us got different ideas.

Comment: I agree this is ambiguous - I read the request as substring removal but it could equally be whole string removal.

Comment: Do you mean word, or letters?

Comment: @AChampion: On re-reading this, I hope you're correct from a linguistic standpoint; but if you are, then this shouldn't have been posted in the first place.

Comment: Down-votes for the question and up-votes for answers! Please tell me what's wrong with my question that needs down-voting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and `.replace('bcd', '')`, e.g.:

```
In []: [s.replace('bcd', '') for s in string_list]
Out[]: ['aefg', 'qwrqqq', 'ophdkjhfk', 'jdfkvndn']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string_list = [temp.replace('bcd','') for temp in string_list]
```

Comment: how's it really different from Champion's answer???

Comment: we answered as the same time

Comment: okay upvote u will get 1000 repo :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new list of those words which do *not* include the target substring.

```
target = "bcd"
new_list = [word for word in string_list if not target in word]
```